# How to access nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Machine: `Ubuntu 18.06` running on a VPS (technically a server). The cluster is set up with `kubeadm`.
**Problem:** I am not able to hit the controller via `domain.com/`

So, basically I simply executed these two ymls:

> kubectl apply -f
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: udp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-role
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      # Defaults to "<election-id>-<ingress-class>"
      # Here: "<ingress-controller-leader>-<nginx>"
      # This has to be adapted if you change either parameter
      # when launching the nginx-ingress-controller.
      - "ingress-controller-leader-nginx"
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-role-nisa-binding
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: nginx-ingress-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
    namespace: ingress-nginx

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
    namespace: ingress-nginx

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "10254"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
            - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
            - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
            - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            # www-data -> 33
            runAsUser: 33
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

---

> kubectl apply -f
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
```

> The nginx controller is up and running and it takes care about the
>   other scripts.

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-766c77b7d4-8sbrh   1/1     Running   0          46m
```

> The logs of the ingress controller loading ingresses:

```
I1225 11:39:43.663283       9 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"articleservice-ingress", UID:"c5d24d09-0839-11e9-a12a-0050563e015b", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"117205", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/articleservice-ingress
I1225 11:39:43.663499       9 controller.go:172] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I1225 11:39:43.893031       9 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"cartservice-ingress", UID:"c5f6051e-0839-11e9-a12a-0050563e015b", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"117208", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/cartservice-ingress
I1225 11:39:43.902002       9 controller.go:190] Backend successfully reloaded.
[25/Dec/2018:11:39:43 +0000]TCP200000.000
I1225 11:39:44.169490       9 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"catalogservice-ingress", UID:"c62008a1-0839-11e9-a12a-0050563e015b", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"117211", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/catalogservice-ingress
I1225 11:39:46.634113       9 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"customerservice-ingress", UID:"c7984c98-0839-11e9-a12a-0050563e015b", APIVersion:"extensions/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"117215", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/customerservice-ingress
I1225 11:39:46.997363       9 controller.go:172] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
[25/Dec/2018:11:39:47 +0000]TCP200000.000
I1225 11:39:47.242642       9 controller.go:190] Backend successfully reloaded.
```

**Now I expect I am able to access the controller via `domain.com/` (should return 404) the other ingresses which are registered via `domain.com/ingress`**

I guess I missed something very basic. If you need any further information just let me know.

> Output of `kubectl -n ingress-nginx describe service/ingress-nginx`

```
Name:                     ingress-nginx
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/par...
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.100.48.223
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30734/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.0.8:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32609/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.0.8:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: what is `domain.com` (along with domain.com/ingress) exactly? What is your target?

Comment: `domain.com` is the domain of the server where the cluster is running on. Once I had a nginx container with static html content and I could reach this one via `domain.com`, so I expected I gonna hit the ingress controller that way as well. `domain.com/ingress` should  hit the ingress with path `/ingress` defined.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `kubectl -n ingress-nginx describe service/ingress-nginx`?
Make sure you are trying to access the right port (nodePort).

Comment: Thats it ;D I can access it via the nodeport.... Any idea how I can redirect incoming traffic on port 80 to that nodeport?

Comment: Try hitting the server where nginx is running.  For example, it is running on http://server1.domain.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All credits to @Konstantin Vustin  and @rom. I noticed I can access the ingress controller via the `NodePort` 30734.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [MetalLB](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#a-pure-software-solution-metallb).

This way you can use standard ports and predefined set of IP addresses to access your resources. It also allows you to create Services types of `LoadBalancer` with issued `ExternalIP` on bare metal installation of Kubernetes cluster.